# Amazon Monitor Global SMS Delivery Status

Tags: .net, amazon-sns

I'm working on using Amazon SNS to deliver Global SMS messages using .Net Application
i try to send SMS to phone directly using Admin credential 
using this code :

```
Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();
smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "mySender", DataType = "String" });//The sender ID shown on the device.
smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "0.50", DataType = "Number" });//Sets the max price to 0.50 USD.
 smsAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", new MessageAttributeValue() { StringValue = "Transactional", DataType = "String" });//Sets the type to promotional.
PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest(){Message = message, PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,MessageAttributes = smsAttributes};
PublishResponse response = snsClient.Publish(request);
```

my Question is :
how i monitor the Message delivery Status ? 
response has message Id without delivery status like success or failure

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed,

The [SNS Worldwide SMS Messaging Blog](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxSP0HUNM8FQ1Y/Introducing-Worldwide-SMS-Messaging) has instructions for enabling delivery status specifically for SMS. Once enabled, SNS will log ALL SMS success/failures to [CloudWatch Logs](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logs:). The CW Log Groups for SMS have the following format:

**Success**: sns/us-east-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber

**Failure**: sns/us-east-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber/Failure

[SNS text messaging preferences](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home?region=us-east-1#/text-messaging/preferences) (us-east-1)

Also, the SMS MessageAttributes you specified in the .NET code are optional. You can also set the default price, type, and Sender ID via the SMS text messaging preferences per region.

Hope this helps,

-Dennis

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't got why they are returning message id in return or is there any way to get message status from that id.

Till now what my finding is, you can only log the delivery status in cloudwatch.

In cloudwatch it makes groups for **successful** and **failure** message status.

you can check this out: https://mobile.awsblog.com/blog/author/Arjun+Cholkar